# Is there any relationship between Secure Boot and Kernel Lockdown?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, bootloader, lockdown, linux-security-module

As far as I googled till now, the two features seem independent.

Secure Boot is dependent on Kernel Signature, so the bootloader will be checking (Kernel/Single Image Application) Signature if Valid will Call Kernel Start Function.

Lockdown is another feature where "The lockdown code is intended to allow for kernels to be locked down early in boot - sufficiently early that we don't have the ability to `kmalloc()` yet. Disallowing even privileged User from accessing Confidential Data present in kernel memory."

Lockdown comes in via boot parameters/sysfs control after kernel is authenticated to be 
valid.

Is my understanding correct?

So with a Secure Boot Disabled, the Lockdown Feature should still work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I'd say that your understanding is correct.

**Secure boot** is a security feature implemented in hardware (i.e. directly in your CPU, though it could also be implemented in UEFI firmware). It's a mechanism of verification that is done as the very first thing when powering on the computer. Some known public keys are stored in hardware and are used to verify the signature of the bootloader before running it. The process can be then repeated through the multiple stages of the boot process where each stage verifies the following one until the OS is started. To know more, take a look at [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot) of the Debian documentation about secure boot.

**Kernel lockdown** is a security feature of the Linux kernel, which was recently introduced in version 5.4 as an optional security module. As mentioned in [this interesting article from LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/751061/), the purpose of kernel lockdown is to enforce a distinction between running as root and the ability to run code in kernel mode. Depending on the configuration, kernel lockdown can disable features of the kernel that allow modifications of the running kernel or the extraction of confidential information from userspace. Take a look at [the relevant commit message](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=aefcf2f4b58155d27340ba5f9ddbe9513da8286d) that introduced the feature to Linux.

**The relationship between secure boot and kernel lockdown** can be explained by this very important consideration (from the same LWN article linked above):

> Proponents of UEFI secure boot maintain that this separation [i.e. kernel lockdown] is necessary; otherwise the promise of secure boot (that the system will only run trusted code in kernel mode) cannot be kept. Closing off the paths by which a privileged attacker could run arbitrary code in kernel mode requires disabling a number of features in the kernel.

In other words, one could argue that secure boot is useless if the kernel that is verified and ran can be then modified by userland processes. Indeed, without proper kernel hardening, a potential attacker could exploit privileged userland processes to alter the running kernel and therefore tear down the whole security model of the system.

On the other hand, one could as easily argue that kernel lockdown is useless without secure boot since a potential attacker could compromise the boot chain (e.g. modifying the bootloader or the kernel image on the disk) and make the machine run a modified kernel on the next boot.

Nonetheless, **the two features are independent of each other**. There are still valid use cases of secure boot without kernel lockdown, and vice versa kernel lockdown without secure boot. It all ultimately depends on what's your [threat model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model).

Comment: "Secure boot is a security feature implemented in hardware (i.e. directly in your CPU)" - IIRC, it is implemented in many (but not all) variants of UEFI firmware rather than in hardware itself. Hardware may or may not be involved here directly. The trusted keys can also be stored in UEFI firmware only. Some systems may have them in hardware as well, I guess.